# What is the meaning of "dimensionality of the embeddings and hidden states"?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, natural-language-processing, recurrent-neural-networks, transformer

I was reading the GPT-2 and LSTM documents and noticed that they use the terms "dimension of embedding and hidden state". For GPT-2, the size is $768$, and for LSTM, the size is $256$. What does that mean ? Are there any visual graphs or figures for these concepts ? Very difficult to understand any of this.

Thanks

Comment: Could you specify which documents you are referring to? In NLP, we vectorize tokens and must assign them a number of dimensions. This is a hyperparameter that we can change, and it's normally determined through experimentation. 'Hidden States' is a term used in RNNs, where we have an output that changes over a number of iterations to process all the tokens in the sequence. These are the intermediate values of the recurrent operation that are passed to the next state in the sequence. These are not the same and to my undertanding they can be of different sizes.

Comment: @CesarRuiz, Thanks for your reply, do word embeddings and hidden states have the same meaning ?

Comment: No, they refer to different things. Think of word embeddings as a dictionary where you look up a word (token) and it gives you a definition (the vector). So, whenever the model uses a token, it replaces it with its vectorial representation. The hidden states in an RNN are vectors that hold information from previous tokens in the sequence. This is how RNNs can retain information from previous tokens in a efficient way.

Comment: @CesarRuiz, I thought Transformer architectures like GPT-2 also have hidden states ?

Comment: We could argue that all neural networks possess hidden states, which are the outputs of the hidden layers, but the term 'hidden states' is usually associated with RNNs. Hidden states are linked to sequential data, meaning that the current step requires the previous step for calculation. This is not the case with Transformers, because Transformers do not process data sequentially. Instead, they parallelize the data and then combine it through concatenation.

Comment: @CesarRuiz, [In this document about GPT-2](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/gpt2#transformers.GPT2Model), there is a function called `GPT2Model` that is used to output raw hidden states ?

Comment: Yes. In this scenario, `raw hidden state`' refer to the individual outputs of each attention block. This class have the option of saving all the outputs of the attention blocks in the variable `all_hidden_states` as a tensor. Here, hidden_states refer to the output of a layer. The term hidden_state has a different meaning in the context of RNNs, not just the output of a layer. That's why the first thing I asked was about your resources, because the meaning of the term can change depending on the context :)

Comment: @CesarRuiz, Thanks for clarifying. One more question: The description of the class [GPT2Model](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/gpt2#transformers.GPT2Model) also mentions `without any specific head on top`. What does this mean ? Do you know ? Thanks

Comment: Based on the documentation, "head on top" refers to the addition of a layer to a model for the purpose of fine-tuning it to a specific task. This is a technique for fast fine-tuning of the model. You can see this if you look at the `GPT2LMHeadModel` class, which explains what "head on top" is. Basically, they are just using the vanilla GPT2 pretrained model without anything else on top.

Comment: Thanks for your help.